# What is the glb and the lub for the spectral radius of a nonnegative matrix with row sum either 1 or 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What is the greatest lower bound and the least upper bound for the spectral radius of a nonnegative matrix with row sum either 1 or 0 (cannot be all zeros)? Also diagonal entries of that matrix are zero.

Which theorems can I apply here, assuming the matrix is reducible? I only know the spectral radius of that matrix must be within (0,1). Any idea how to improve it?

Comment: What is g.l.b. and l.u.b. on the spectral radius?

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel the greatest lower bound and the least upper bound

Comment: If a nonnegative matrix has zero row sums, these rows are necessarily zero. In that case, the matrix is reducible to the form $\pmatrix{A&B\\0&0}$ where the rectangular block $[A,B]$ has unit row sums. The spectrum of the whole matrix is then given by the spectrum of $A$ plus some zeros.

Comment: I understand the meaning of the letters, why g.l.b. and l.u.b. on a single number would make sense since they are equal to that number itself.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel sorry I should have said that this is not a single matrix. In the question I meant the class of nonnegative matrix, with row sum 1 or 0 and diagonal entries are zero. So you are saying the bound (0,1) can not improve?

Comment: If a matrix of such a class is transformed to $\pmatrix{A&B\\0&0}$, then you can improve at least the upper bound, e.g., by computing the row sums of $A$.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Thank you. That is helpful.